# Javascript:Select from array.push()

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I have this array.push function:

```
users.push({
    username: username,
    rank: 0
});
```

And I need to select how many username`s are in the users array:

```
console.log(username + " joined the chat. "+ users[username].length +" chatters online now!");
```

But this isnot working:

> Cannot read property of 'length' of undefined

So, how select the username`s?

Comment: `users` is not an associative array. Why not just check the `.length` property of the `users` array?

Comment: You can include the number of users with `users.length`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that `users.length` will do the trick, given that your use of the `push` function indicates that `users` is a linear or non-associative array. However, if you want to find how many objects in the `users` array actually have defined `username` properties, you'll want to loop through it:

```
var i = users.length,
    usernameLength;

while(i--) {
    if(users[i].username !== undefined) {
        usernameLength++;
    }
}

// usernameLength represents the amount of users in the users array that have defined usernames
username + " joined the chat. "+ usernameLength +" chatters online now!");
```

Comment: +1 to differentiate from other answers because correct. Also a short tip. You don't need that `typeof` check - you can do `users[i].username !== undefined`. Or even better - `users.filter(function(user){ return users[i].username; })`

Comment: Thanks. And you're right. The `typeof` check was sheer force of habit. :)

Comment: Works, but how do I get the index of a username?

Comment: That depends. What username are you trying to find the index of?

Answer (score 0):

You push an object, users is an array with numbers as keys, each element being and object with username and rank as params.

Try: users[0].username.

Answer (score 0):

if would use the [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to create a new array with all objects with an username, and count that length:

```
var filtered = users.filter(function (user) {
  return user.username && user.username.length > 0;
});

console.log(filtered.length);
```

in one line:

```
var length = (users.filter(function (user) { return user.username && user.username.length > 0 })).length
```